# Do iOS and iPadOS alert you if the certificate of a network you’re joining has changed

Tags: network, wifi, security

So if you joined a network in the past and trusted its certificate while at it, and saved it on your iPhone/iPad.

Sometime later, if either:

1. It’s the same network but their previous certificate has expired and they’re now using a new one

or

2. Your device finds another network with the same SSID, which does not have the same certificate (has no certificate or has a different certificate)

Will your iPhone/iPad alert you or will it quietly join without asking you about anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you join the same network, and they have renewed their certificate - you will not get an an alert (assuming that the new certificate is indeed valid).

Comment: What about if it’s a different network with no certificate?